# How to add Additonal charge on COD in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hi i am looking to add an extra field here in cod and also i want to charge extra 100 rs/- handling fee but dont know how to achieve this anyone had ever tried this kindly please provide some solution on how to achieve this

[image]

Comment: You can use this extension: https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-multi-cash-on-delivery-cod/

Comment: Not a native feature you may either code it or use a third party plugin. I can recommend https://www.magedelight.com/extra-fee-magento-2.html as I had used this in one of our project for same requirement.

Comment: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee should try this ex

Comment: i dont want to use extension i just want to override it with plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various free and paid modules already available for this. You can have a look at these:

- https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee (Free)
- https://marketplace.magento.com/themecafe2016-cash-on-delivery.html (Paid)

If you want to create your own module for it, you may need to:

- override/observe/create a plugin for payment model
- create extension attribute for example extra fee
- override some areas like order view section in backend and customer order section etc.

I hope it helped.

Comment: i dont want to use extension i just want to override it with plugin

Comment: Then you can download the free module and check it's code. Implement what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cash on Delivery Fee extension (https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee) that is free.

This module adds a configurable fee for the Magento2 default cash on delivery payment method. Instead of overriding a few files it will be better to use extension because it's also doing some additional changes in order and other pages.
So it's reliable to use a module for that.